# Galois group of $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$. Let $E = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. We are given that $\beta = \alpha^2 - 2$ is also a root, and I need to find $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ and show that $E$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This is what I was thinking: because we have a relation between two roots, then they are both complex or both real. If they are both real, then you have 2 real roots so thus all 3 roots are real. In that case, then the Galois group is $S_3$ or $A_3$..? Or can we say that $\gamma = \beta^2 -2$ is also a root, so then they must all be real? I'm having trouble with figuring our the Galois group when a relation is given like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: The relation doesn't mean theyre both complex or both real, look at $x^4 - 1$ for example then $-1=i^2$ is a root and so is $i$.

Comment: Ah I see. Well I looked at the graph and it indeed has 3 real roots, so I tried to work backward from that. So what do we do with this relation then? If they are all real, then are we down to at most $A_3$?

Comment: @DanZimm The polynomial $x^4 - 1$ is reducible, so this is not an apt comparison.  The roots of an irreducible polynomial are algebraically indistinguishable, so the OP is justified in assuming that $\alpha$ is the real root of the given cubic.

Comment: @SpamIAm I wasn't saying it that he was wrong in his conclusion, I was simply saying his reasoning was wrong. He would be justified in saying that if he acknowledged that he's able to do that (since they're algebraically indistinguishable). Nonetheless since $\alpha = \beta^2 - 1$ there is no way for $\alpha$ to be complex - $\beta^2$ will always be real and so is $-1$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root, $\alpha^2-1$ is not a root, but $\alpha^2-2$ is.

Comment: @mercio Thanks, was a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I think the point is that $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. So since the polynomial is of third degree $E$ will also contain the third root and therefore is the splitting field.
It is normal since splitting fields are normal. The degree is three and there is only one group of order three.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, this is the minimal polynomial of $z + z^{-1}$, where $z$ is a primitive $7$-th root of unity. This hint also leads to the result that the Galois group is cyclic of order $3$.

This explains the fact that if $$\alpha = z + z^{-1}$$ is a root, then $$\alpha^{2} - 2 = (z^{2} + z^{-2} + 2) - 2 = z^{2} + (z^{2})^{-1}$$ is also a root.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "This hint also leads to the result that the Galois group is cyclic of order 3," did you arrive at this conclusion because $z+z^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$, i.e. it has no complex part? So do you see it as $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ "without" the $i$?

Comment: @user121937, $z + z^{-1}$ is not rational. Rather, $\mathbb{Q}(z)/\mathbb{Q}$ has Galois group which is cyclic of order $6$, and $\mathbb{Q}(z + z^{-1})$ is the fixed field of complex conjugation, which is an automorphism of order $2$. Therefore the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(z + z^{-1})/\mathbb{Q}$ has order $3$.